# Acessing elements of a sort w/ multiple fields

Tags: z3, smt

I'm having some trouble using sorts in the SMTlib2 format. For example, I define an Interval as:

```
(declare-sort Pair 2)
(define-sort Interval () (Pair Int Int))
```

Now how can I return a new Interval from a function? e.g.:

```
(define-fun getInterval ((a Int) (b Int)) Interval
  (Interval a b))
```

This doesn't work.
My question is: how can I construct and instantiate objects of a given sort, and how can I access their fields?

Right now I'm using 2 UFs that I created as field getters, but I still don't know how to have a constructor:

```
(declare-fun L (Interval) Int)
(declare-fun H (Interval) Int)
```

Thanks,
Nuno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [Record subsection, Datatypes section in Z3 SMT guide](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h27). Basically, you can create a record type with a constructor `mk-pair` and two selectors `first` and `second` for accessing its fields.

Here is an example<sup>[rise4fun link](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/KQ1)</sup>:

```
(set-option :macro-finder true)

(declare-datatypes (T1 T2) ((Pair (mk-pair (first T1) (second T2)))))

(define-sort Interval () (Pair Int Int))
(define-fun getInterval ((a Int) (b Int)) Interval
  (mk-pair a b))

(declare-const p1 Interval)
(declare-const p2 Interval)

;construct objects of a give sort
(assert (= p1 (getInterval 2 2)))

;accessing their fields
(assert (= (first p1) (second p2)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Comment: Thanks.
I still wonder what's the usefulness of sorts consisting of multiple "sub-sorts".

Comment: This is a good point. I agree with you, they are essentially useless from the user point of view. Z3 supports them because they are part of the SMT-LIB 2.0 standard. However, they are useful for specifying the semantics of background theories (see: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/ArraysEx.smt2). However, your point is still valid, since the `par` construct can only be used in the definition of background theories, and cannot be used by SMT 2.0  users.